# Is it possible to write generics in a way that still enforces type safety?

Tags: typescript, generics, design-patterns, types, interface

Let's say I have multiple classes that have a similar method. In this case, a bunch of services that have a saveModel method:

```js
public async saveModel(newModel: IModel): Promise<IModel> {
    return await newModel.save();
}
```

The generic method I made looks like this:

```typescript
public async saveModel<P extends Document>(newModel: P): Promise<P> {
    return await newModel.save();
}
```

All of my services (the ones that use that method) extend a class that contains that generic method, so now on any of those services, I can call `answerService.saveModel(newAnswer)` and it'll save the answer. Everything was dandy until I realized that I can put an object of type IQuestion in there as well. And an object of type IDinosaur if I wanted, as long as it extends the Mongoose Document interface.

Is there any way for me to enforce certain interfaces to be used in each service? How would I make sure that the answerService only saves objects with type IAnswer? Does the answerService need to implement an interface that has that saveModel signature like this:

```typescript
interface IAnswerService {
    saveModel(newModel: IAnswer): Promise<IAnswer>;
}
```

This is a skeleton of what the entire thing looks like:

EntityService.ts

```typescript
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
export class EntityService implements IEntityService {
  public async saveModel<P extends Document>(newModel: P): Promise<P> {
    try {
      const savedModel = await newModel.save();
      return savedModel;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

answer.service.ts

```typescript
import { Answer, IAnswer } from '@models/answer.model';
import { EntityService } from '@classes/EntityService';

class AnswerService extends EntityService {
  private static instance: AnswerService;

  private constructor() {
    super();
  }

  static getInstance(): AnswerService {
    if (!AnswerService.instance) {
      AnswerService.instance = new AnswerService();
    }

    return AnswerService.instance;
  }
}

const answerService = AnswerService.getInstance();
export default answerService;
```

answer.model.ts

```typescript
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, Model } from 'mongoose';

export interface IAnswer extends Document {
  answerText: string;
  posterID: string;
}

const AnswerSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  answerText: {type: String, required: true},
  posterID: {type: String, required: true}
}, {
  minimize: false
});

export const Answer: Model<IAnswer> = mongoose.model<IAnswer>('Answer', AnswerSchema);
```

All other interfaces inherit from the same things that IAnswer does (Model, Schema, Document).

And usage of the AnswerService looks generally like this:

```typescript
import answerService from 'answer.service';
import { Answer } from 'answer.model';

const answer = new Answer({
    answerText: 'Stuff',
    posterID: '123456789'
})

answerService.saveModel(answer);
```

Comment: Could you make the code a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to demonstrate what you're seeing?  I don't think I quite understand your class/interface hierarchy well enough to make a suggestion here.  You might want [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) or some other type mapping, but I'll need some kind of skeleton for `IQuestion`, `IAnswer`, etc  to understand

Comment: I don't use the Playground a lot, so I'm not entirely sure if you can import from mongoose in it, but I just uploaded the general skeleton. Keep in mind I am planning on doing away with the singleton patterns. I didn't realize those are viewed as an anti-pattern across the board

Comment: I'm going to get rid of `IEntityService` when I analyze this because there doesn't seem to be a definition for it

Comment: Yeah, I left it out because as of right now, it doesn't really add much, it just declares an interface with this line in it: ```saveModel<P extends Document>(newModel: P, changedParam: string): Promise<P>;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want each subclass of `EntityService` to handle a particular subtype of `Document`.  If so, then you don't want `saveModel()` to be generic in `P extends Document`; you want the whole `EntityService` class to be generic in `P`.  And each subclass of `EntityService` should specify that generic type parameter.  For example:

```
// P moved to EntityService from saveModel    
export class EntityService<P extends Document> {
  public async saveModel(newModel: P): Promise<P> {
    try {
      const savedModel = await newModel.save();
      return savedModel;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return null!;
    }
  }
}

// subclass sets specific value for P   
class AnswerService extends EntityService<IAnswer> {
  private static instance: AnswerService;   
  private constructor() {
    super();
  }    
}
```

Then later, if you have an `answer` of type `IAnswer` and a `document` only known to be of type `Document`, then an `AnswerService` will only allow you to `saveModel(answer)` and not `saveModel(document)`:

```
AnswerService.getInstance().saveModel(answer); // okay
AnswerService.getInstance().saveModel(document); // error, Document is not IAnswer
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBCCA7A5hCBnApgGjgbzgGUBjACyxAEM8ARCEgVxCyRjwFkIATLAGzgBfOADMoEEHADkiVOmxSA3AFgAUGqwAPSLDgk+VDBjgBRNsBgBPIligA3YCSwAeAApwtMVt2P0mLNgA+AjU4ODBGACM+RzhDSyQSOAwqOywuXj4ACiQsAHcM-gAuOFcAShLXcRBgbDdg-FCwuBgoSxDVZuaSZAx4FLTuQoEAXji8qgs4XIKefgA6AawsspVOrrgoLBhGKCRk1Kwhub41ruESKhhyOCzbKDKOjb1eiD4seb4IFDuoB7ONlsdntpow+HwAIQAsKCJqw1TwuAabTQeDANi2ERUJxwACSAEEkBg8rYPJovEgfHA-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-h0tFcUeH80B0C5nlwLU0wQPA+oCUAA)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for